# does disabling trust evaluation for localhost server add security issue

Tags: ios, alamofire

I'm disabling trust evaluation for my localhost server.
Does this configuration add any security issues in release?

```
private static var manager: Alamofire.SessionManager = {

    // Create the server trust policies
    let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
        "localhost": .disableEvaluation
    ]

    // Create custom manager
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = Alamofire.SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders
    let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager(
        configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default,
        serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
    )

    return manager
}()
```

Thanks

Comment: "Disabling server trust evaluation puts the user's security at risk. Do not do it in any code you intend to ship to end users. If server trust evaluation is failing, you must understand why it's failing and decide on the best way to resolve that failure."

You can refer this for more reference https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2232/_index.html

Comment: Im only disabling evaluation for localhost, production server obviously isn't localhost

Comment: Obviously!. A good practice could be a self-signed certificate, which is a reasonable approach during development, This approach has the advantage that you don't need to disable server trust evaluation during development, which means that you can't forget to re-enable it when you ship a production build.

Comment: I have a self signed certificate but im still getting this TLS trust error, that is the reason i'm disabling evaluation.